# Office 365 - Word - Disable track changes

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an elderly neighbor whom I help with his computer problems. Since he got a new PC he's been forced to use Office 365 instead of his old Word 2007.

During the war he got hit by shrapnel at the head which causes him to have tremors at his hands. This makes him click the wrong small icons, press the wrong keys.

Lately he's been having problems with his printouts, because he accidentally manages to turn on something like the "track changes" functionality. I am not a MS Office user, so I always have to find out by trial and error what is going on, and leave shaking my head at Microsoft's user-friendliness.

I found this article on [Turn off track changes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-track-changes-85a31f26-d593-42eb-9fe1-2fdf081d18f6), but this only deals with a specific document.

Is it possible to turn off all this change tracking for all documents, and make it really hard to enable it?

Is there something like a "senior mode" for Word, where all the advanced stuff is simply removed from the UI and the keyboard shortcuts? No need for tables, comments, and all that stuff which office workers do need.

---

Update:

I now visited him since he lost some text, which luckily still was in his clipboard, and looked closer at the issue.

The problem is the following: When he got the new computer, his son added himself as an account to office, so that all the data gets synced to his cloud. Now, when the old man uses Word as usual, he is actually modifying the document in the name of his son, so everything he does is not a normal edit to the old document. The old document is a ".doc" file. Not ".docx" or ".odt". Apparently ".odt" is set as the predefined file format, but that is off-topic.

When I switch the account to the one of his computer, which is in his name, all that changes is the color of the annotation, as if now a second additional editor is modifying the document.

I don't know how to tell Word to be none of these accounts, but the original author of the document, so that all modifications are nothing which requires approval.

How can this be done?

Comment: What are the functions he use? If it's really only typing, then I'd suggest notepad.  You can also hide menu bar with CTRL+F1 in Word.

Comment: Notpad and non-`docx` formats are not an option. He has an arsenal of letters, and when writing a new letter to someome he opens the last letter he wrote to that person, adds a line break, and writes the new letter in the same document, then prints out the latest, relevant pages. I'm thinking along the lines of installing him TextMaker 2016, but I first need to test it myself to see if he can deal with it.